# How do I test this simple index method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, nunit

I'm trying to test a very simple controller index method, which is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   try
   {
       var indexViewModel = new IndexViewModel { SearchViewModel = new SearchViewModel() };
       return View(indexViewModel);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Log.Debug("Index method exception: ", e);
       Session["errorMessage"] = e;
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
   }
}
```

and the test I'm trying is this:

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIndexView()
    {
        //Arrange
        var controller = new HomeController();

        //Act
        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
    }
}
```

But when I run the test, I get the following error;

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Index>,Actual<>
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Can you post the full exception message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewName` property is null or an empty string, since you didn't specify it in your `return View(...)` method call. This is likely intended behavior, because the framework will infer the view name if you did not specify one.

It looks like your expected result is actually `null` instead of `"Index"`.